Are questions regarding publications/subscriptions on topic?
The title really says it all. I often find myself wanting to know more about the publications and subscriptions available as so many of the references are inaccessible to me. If I ask a question about those would that be an acceptable question?

Questions about the publication process are permitted as long as they are Psychology, Neuroscience, or Cognitive Science specific:
Are questions about the publication process in psychology and cognitive science permitted?
For general questions about publications/subscriptions consider asking on Academia.SE.
If you need help gaining access to specific articles, consider:
How can I access a journal article if I don't have a subscription?
or ask in chat. A question on the main site of cogsci.SE asking for access to a specific article that is easy to find but behind a pay-wall would be off-topic, and answering it might be a violation of copyright (Damn you big publishers!).
